# Hyperparameter Optimization of net structure with Pytorch

Tags: neural-network, pytorch, layer, hyperparameters

I have built a neural net with a custom architecture, as designed below.
No I wanted to perform a hyperparameter optimization in order to find the optimal learning rate, batch size, but also the number of neurons per hidden layer and the number of layers.

I have three sperate NN in the beginning which concatenated and then processed again through some dense layers.

Until now I haven't found a way to tune the number of layers in Pytorch hyperparameter optimization.
Ideally, I would also like to test whether the three nets need a different number of layers.

```
class Individual(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Individual, self).__init__()
        self.fc1_left = nn.Linear(30, 24)
        self.fc1_right = nn.Linear(30, 24)
        self.fc1_cor = nn.Linear(2, 4)
        self.fc2_cor = nn.Linear(4, 4)
        self.fc2_left = nn.Linear(24,4)
        self.fc2_right = nn.Linear(24,4)
        self.fc3 = nn.Linear(12, 36)
        self.fc4 = nn.Linear(36,num_classes)
        self.Sigmoid_left = nn.Sigmoid()
        self.Sigmoid_right = nn.Sigmoid()

    def forward(self, x_left, x_right, x_cor, x_con):
        
        x_con_l = x_con[:,0].view(-1, 1)
        x_con_r = x_con[:,1].view(-1, 1)        
     
        x_left = F.relu(self.fc1_left(x_left))
        x_left = F.relu(self.fc2_left(x_left))
        x_left = torch.mul(x_left, x_con_l)

        x_right = F.relu(self.fc1_right(x_right))
        x_right = F.relu(self.fc2_right(x_right))
        x_right = torch.mul(x_right, x_con_r)   
        
        x_cor = F.relu(self.fc1_cor(x_cor))
        x_cor = F.relu(self.fc2_cor(x_cor))
        
        
        combined = torch.cat((x_left.view(x_left.size(0), -1),
                          x_right.view(x_right.size(0), -1)), dim=1)

        combined = torch.cat((combined.view(combined.size(0), -1),
                          x_cor.view(x_cor.size(0), -1)), dim=1)        
        
        x1 = F.relu(self.fc3(combined))
        x2 = F.relu(self.fc4(x1))
        
        return x2
```

Comment: How are you going to optimize hyper-parameters exactly?

Comment: Hi Ivan, I was going to use one of the methods that are available. But I haven't one where you can change the number of layers nor take into account three different nets followed up by concatenation.

Comment: You could do that with 3rd party tools such as [Weight&Biases](https://wandb.ai/) or [Optuna](https://optuna.org/), I believe you can also do it with Tensorboard...

Comment: Hi Ivan, I solved it by using Ray.tune(). However, the number of layers as hyperparameter is still an open point for me.